# Cannot understand why spread operator is used

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I'm using ngx-charts (charts library for Angular2+) and I found this line of code that I don't understand.

```
@Input() activeEntries: any[] = [];

/* ... */

/* Then, in a function */
this.activeEntries = [...this.activeEntries];
```

To me, it has no effect. Do you know this usage and what it does ?

Thank you

Comment: Array is an object. Object in JS are assign using reference. So if you directly assign it, both variables will point to same location. `[...this.activeEntries]` This will make a copy. This is same as `array.slice(0)`

Comment: To create a new array rather than copying a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *spreading* the contents of `this.activeEntries` inside an array literal this code is creating a *copy* of that array.

It's then assigning a reference to that copy back to `this.activeEntries` overwriting the original reference held.  It is unclear from the context given why that is necessary.

Comment: Question: any reason this is preferable to the more direct and clear `Array.from()`?

Comment: I expect it's just for consistency - the same library makes a lot of use of `array = [ new_element, ... array ]` as a prepend operation.